# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: not working

Tags: arrays

Why am i getting this error ? I am trying to sort from small to greater in the int array and print it but its not working. I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10
        at Bubblesort.bubbleSort(Bubblesort.java:26)
        at Bubblesort.main(Bubblesort.java:47)
```

Source code:

```
class Bubblesort {
    
    static String arrayToString(int[] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++ ){ 
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
        System.out.print(",");
        }
        return null;
        
    }
    
    static int[] randomArray(int n) {
        java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++ ){ 
            int random = rand.nextInt(99);
            array[i] = random;
        }
        return array;   
    }

    
    static void bubbleSort(int[] arr){
        for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++ ) {
            if ( arr[i] > arr[i+1] ) {
                arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1] = arr[i];
            } else {
                arr[i] = arr[i];    
            }
        }
    }                                 
    


public static void main (String[] args) {

    int[] test10 = randomArray(10);
    int[] test20 = randomArray(20);
    int[] test30 = randomArray(30);
    
    arrayToString(test10);
    System.out.println("");
    arrayToString(test20);
    System.out.println("");
    arrayToString(test30);
    System.out.println("");
    

    bubbleSort(test10);
    arrayToString(test10);
    System.out.println("");
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: In your bubblesort function you are trying to compare to arr[i+1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array has ten elements, indexed from 0 to 9.

In the `for` loop inside your `bubblesort` function, you iterate over all these elements, letting `i` go from zero to nine.

The first thing you do here is compare  `arr[i]` and `arr[i+1]`.  When `i` is nine, that means you're trying to compare `arr[9]` to `arr[10]`.  But there is no such thing as `arr[10]`.  Your array index is out of bounds, hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.